# Microsoft Publisher document not opening from OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-publisher

I created a document in Microsoft Publisher (Windows 11) and saved it in OneDrive.

I tried opening it through the "open" option in Publisher, and also through Windows File Explorer but I get the same results. Either it won't open and it tells me:

> "Cannot download the information you requested"

[image]

Or it opens in read only mode. I tried setting the FileSizeLimitInBytes registry key to a higher number, as recommended in this [Microsoft Support Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/large-publisher-files-open-in-read-only-mode) but it didn't help me.

Comment: If you love the downloaded file to another directory, what happens?

Comment: @Ramhound; Sorry I didn't understand, you mean download the file?

Comment: The file currently exists as an uploaded file within your OneDrive account, download the file, then try to open that file in a file other than the OneDrive directory on the system.

Comment: @Ramhound; I can't download the file, I get error 0x800700df

Comment: @EleventhDoctor; maybe you can answer?

Comment: Is OneDrive installed on your computer? What OS is your computer running? How are you trying to open it? Use the EDIT button to add this and other information to your question so we can better understand the full context of the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @music2myear; I tried to to add as much information as I could based on your  comment, is there anything missing?

Comment: @Laurel; More important than the edit, can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: "as recommended in this Microsoft Support Page but it didn't help me" is NOT helping, tell us to what new size you set it. If you want answers you need to communicate more clearly. Comments like " I get error 0x800700df" should be in OP.

Comment: @joep van steen; obviously i tried the amount they recomended. & i'm not the computer expert like you lot, so i dont know what OP is. i just want to be able to open my file